# Filtering businesses, states, and countries out of Google Maps Places Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps Places Autocomplete feature.  I want to scope my autocomplete results to omit businesses and states.  The relevant documentation is at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete.  They provide 2 type collections: `(regions)` and `(cities)`.  `(regions)` includes places categorized as locality, sublocality, postal_code, country, administrative_area1, and administrative_area2.  `(cities)` includes places categorized as locality, and administrative_area1.

My ideal scope would be for places categorized as locality, sublocality, neighborhood, postal_code, and administrative_area3.  Is this possible?

Comment: To omit businesses and states, you could use the `(geocode)` type (see [doc](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3)) which omits businesses and use the [AutocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#summary-of-classes) and filter out results of types you don't need.